# Kernel Compiling Bluetooth error

Tags: bluetooth, kernel

I'm trying to modify and build a new kernel for Samsung S4.

I just do it like [here](https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-nethunter/wiki/Modifying-the-Kernel).

But when I make, I ran into some problems:

Code:

```
drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c: In function '__check_ignore_dga':
drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:1231:1: warning: return from incompatible                  pointer type [enabled by default]
error, forbidden warning: btusb.c:1231
scripts/Makefile.build:307: recipe for target     'drivers/bluetooth/btusb.o' failed
make[2]: *** [drivers/bluetooth/btusb.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:443: recipe for target 'drivers/bluetooth'  failed
make[1]: *** [drivers/bluetooth] Error 2
Makefile:973: recipe for target 'drivers' failed
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

I have google the problem for a couple hours,
but can't find any solution yet.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@jcadduono](https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-nethunter/issues/467#issuecomment-222602173),
it solved my problem.

Here is his solutoin:

> in btusb.c around line 1231 theres probably a module_param 
>   declaration of ignore_dga as a boolean toggle, but ignore_dga is 
>   probably declared near the top of the file as an integer designed for 
>   1 or 0 choices. change it to a bool, so like bool ignore_dga = false; 
>   instead of int ignore_dga = 0; for example

So, I edit the file `drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c`
.

Then, change following code:

```
static int ignore_dga;
static int ignore_csr;
static int ignore_sniffer;
static int disable_scofix;
static int force_scofix;

static int reset = 1;
```

to:

```
static bool ignore_dga;
static bool ignore_csr;
static bool ignore_sniffer;
static bool disable_scofix;
static bool force_scofix;

static bool reset = true;
```

Save and make, it works well.